# Ruby Gem LoadError on Web Browser, but work fine on SSH

Tags: php, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to run a Ruby script that scrapes some URL, and execute it from PHP.

This is my PHP code:

**PHP:**

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com';

$result= shell_exec("ruby script.rb $url");

// Or     $result = `ruby script.rb "$url" 2>&1`; to Debug

echo 'result is:';

echo $result;
```

**Ruby Code:**

```
require 'time'
require 'mechanize' //* or require 'nokogiri', doesn't matter * //

url = ARGV.first

begin
  page = Mechanize.new.get(url).content
  result = page.match(/findMe: "\$(.+)"/)[1].tr(',', '')

  # Uncomment following line to see date and time in output
  # output = Time.now.strftime('[%F %T %z] ') + result

  # Uncomment following line to see only result in output
  output = result

  # Output the result on terminal
  puts result

rescue => detail
  puts detail.message
end
```

From SSH, I am able to execute the PHP fine:

`php run.php`

But When I try to load this PHP file from a web browser, I get:

> result is:script.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- mechanize
>   (LoadError) from script.rb:2

I tried defining paths, using `PWD` for full path of ruby script, and `ruby which` to get path of ruby itself, but it didn't change anything.

**Three Ruby developers I took weren't able to figure this out so far.**

Server is runnign apache.

Comment: You need to require 'rubygems' and 'bundler/setup' also in the Ruby script

Comment: Sounds familiar. I think the script can't find your gems. Maybe your gems are installed under a user other than the one executing the script. If you are using rbenv, rbenv init command is in your bashrc or bash_profile and gets executed when you ssh. Maybe you can try executing bash command `source /path/to/bash_profile` from your php script just to see if it works.

Comment: @RadaBogdan in SSH I get error for require `bundler/setup`:

`/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)`

are you sure about it? `rubygems` loads fine, but it didn't help, and it also made it slower.

Comment: @Shiyason gems were installed on root, they apply for all user. for a fact the script is running fine from SSH for the same user, so how could it be user related? I don't know what is `rbenv` can you post your solution as complete answer where to modify what?

Comment: You should not install gems under root unless you're looking for trouble. I suggest uninstalling the system Ruby and use RVM under your user ( not root )